# 'Middle Row' crossword clue in today's Sunday Times concise crossword

Tags: explanation, crossword-clues

In today’s Sunday Times concise crossword, there’s a clue

> (Middle Row) ———- (7)

with brackets and a dash, as shown.

The answer appears to be **Lebanon**. I’m baffled. It’s not a cryptic clue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could this be a reference to (non-crossing) letters that appear in the middle row of the grid?

Comment: The clue posted seems to contain three em-dashes and a hyphen.

Comment: Could you provide us with the entire crossword puzzle, rather than just a single clue? As M Oehm suggested, the clue in question could reference another part of the puzzle.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Considering the typographical convention to type a dash as two hyphens (or minuses), they may just be seven placeholders for the answer.

Comment: Rather an obscure clue for a Concise crossword (or good for lateral thinking). Hopefully the online completion stats will indicate to the setter that s/he might have set a slightly more difficult one than usual?

Answer (score 12):

*Note: A Google search led me to find that this particular clue was also being discussed on the [crosswordsolver.org forum](https://www.crosswordsolver.org/forum/874257/times-concise-1839/) today, where user 'candledave' reported that:*

> *"The middle row of the grid spells CEDAR OF and LEBANON completes the name of the tree". In a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121219/middle-row-crossword-clue?noredirect=1#comment338149_121219) on this question I then advised the asker to take a look at the letters in the middle row of the completed grid; you're expected to substitute these into the 'Middle Row' part of the clue and then complete the expression to find this answer. In response to another user suggesting I post a full answer, here is my attempt to flesh out this finding and comment with full context.*

Here is the crossword in question - The Sunday Times Concise Crossword [#1839](https://extras.thetimes.co.uk/web/pdfs/fb3b81fa2fca1dfaaad8ac73af1a05b6.pdf) - with the relevant crossing answers filled:

> [image: Sunday Times Concise Crossword 1839, partially completed]

Now, with all these other letters known, there is only really one word that can possibly fit in 10D:

> **L**E**B**A**N**O**N** (searching the UKACD dictionary online at [Qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=l.b.n.n&ent=Search&dict=0) suggests this as the only real candidate...).

The question is: how to make sense of the clue "(Middle row) _______"?

> Look at the middle row of the crossword - the letters here spell **CED**?**ROF** when read from left to right. It would appear that the crossword compiler's intention is for the solver to deduce a word for 10D which can form the second part of a phrase, for which these middle-row letters form the first part, and their central letters are the same (due to the overlap in the central cell of the grid).
>
>  i.e. We are looking to find a phrase of the form: **CED?ROF L?B?N?N**. This should lead the solver to **[CEDAR OF LEBANON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedrus_libani)** - the tree for which the country is renowned, meaning that 10D is indeed, safely, **LEBANON**.

*Big credit to user 'candledave' on the crosswordsolver.org forum for their initial post, which helped me to resolve this fully.*

Comment: Thank you all.  I finally got there, but thought it was rather a sneaky clue.